# NGINX+Bolt CMS - static content calls returning 404 errors

Tags: javascript, css, nginx, http-status-code-404, bolt-cms

I decided to try out Bolt CMS on my web server, which has happily run several Wordpress sites for a few months now through PHP-FPM.

The site's front end works apparently fine, but the administration section of the site has problems. Every call to static content -- JS, CSS and image files -- results in a 404 (not found) error. What's more, when I look at the NGINX error logs I see that the server tries to access the files from this location:

/usr/share/nginx/

I don't use that directory anywhere in my nginx or bolt configurations! I've done "grep -R '/usr/share' ." in my nginx and bolt configuration directories, with no results returned.

Has anyone had this problem before? where is the /usr/share/nginx/ reference coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Under distributions like RHEL/CentOS (probably others), `/usr/share/nginx/` is the location of the default Nginx files.  You can `grep -R /etc/nginx` and that will point you to where.

The usual problem that I encounter (create for my own misery) is that I will create the Nginx virtual host file as something like `/etc/nginx/conf.d/example.com` instead of `/etc/nginx/conf.d/example.com.conf` (note the .conf)